# Show mounts under /mnt in File Manager

Tags: mount, nautilus, fstab, disk

I have a few secondary hard disks in my pc, configured in /etc/fstab to be mounted in **/media** at boot time, so they show up as device in file manager (I have nautilus configured as default file manager, but also use nemo).

Now I want to change that **/mnt**, for several reasons, but I want to keep the feature, that each disk is shown in nautilus/nemo as a device.

I tried (soft-) linking the /mnt/disk1... folders to /media/disk1... - but that doesn't do the trick. Is there a trick to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the bind mount method, in order to have your secondary hard drive mounted into two location.

```
mount --bind /mnt/... /media/...
```

In order to make it persistent, modify your fstab.

```
/mnt/...     /media/...    none      bind
```

Don't forget to add this line after all other mounts.

Comment: This totally worked for me. I appreciate it!